# DB2 in Docker container. Problem with autostart of SSL configuration after restarting of Docker container

Tags: docker, db2, systemd, init, autostart

I have a docker container, that started from image – https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2/

Everything is ok, but I need to make few experiments with SSL-connection. I entered inside container.

```
docker exec -it my_container /bin/bash
```

I have switched to needed user

```
su - db2inst1
```

And I made changes, that needed for implementing of SSL configuration

```
gsk8capicmd_64 -keydb -create -db "server.kdb" -pw "my_secret_password" -stash
gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -create -db "server.kdb" -pw "my_secret_password" -label "my_company" -dn "CN=my_company" -size 2048 -sigalg SHA256_WITH_RSA
gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -extract -db "server.kdb" -pw "my_secret_password" -label "my_company" -target "server.arm" -format ascii -fips
gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -details -db "server.kdb" -pw "my_secret_password" -label "my_company"
db2 update dbm cfg using SSL_SVR_KEYDB /database/config/db2inst1/server.kdb
db2 update dbm cfg using SSL_SVR_STASH /database/config/db2inst1/server.sth
db2 update dbm cfg using SSL_SVCENAME 50002
db2set DB2COMM=SSL,TCPIP
db2stop force
db2start
```

Let's check

```
netstat -nlp

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17030/db2sysc 0
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50002           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17030/db2sysc 0
```

Everything is works. I tested SSL, everything is fine. But after, when I am making

```
docker stop my_container 
docker start my_container
```

My SSL-port is not up.  In netstat, I see only:

```
netstat -nlp

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17030/db2sysc 0
```

When I am going to the docker container, and when I am making

```
db2set DB2COMM=SSL,TCPIP
db2stop force
db2start
```

SSL-port is up and everything is fine.

The question. Should I autostart above commands ? Or it can be implemented via some configs in DB2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found file, that is making rewriting of `profile.env`
This file `/var/db2_setup/include/db2_common_functions`, where this string:

```
su - ${DB2INSTANCE?} -c ". sqllib/db2profile; db2set DB2COMM=TCPIP && db2 UPDATE DBM CFG USING DFTDBPATH $DATA_DIR IMMEDIATE"
```

I have replaced on this:

```
su - ${DB2INSTANCE?} -c ". sqllib/db2profile; db2set DB2COMM='TCPIP,SSL' && db2 UPDATE DBM CFG USING DFTDBPATH $DATA_DIR IMMEDIATE"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to temporarily handle this situation is to modify:
`/database/config/db2inst1/sqllib/profile.env`
and in that text file alter the setting for the DB2COMM variable from 'TCPIP' to 'TCPIP,SSL' (or whatever you need).

However, this will only persist while the container exists .

So if you remove the container you will need to redo.

If you simply stop and start the container, the change will persist.

To make the change persist permanently, you would need to alter the image (or make a new image) so that file has the values you need. There may be more elegant solutions.  To modify the image look at the instructions [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2) in the **Build your own** section.

Comment: I already have


DB2COMM='TCPIP,SSL'
DB2AUTOSTART='YES'

in profile.env

.And after stop and start of container I see only port `50000`

Comment: Strange. It works correctly for me. EDIT the question to show the text output of `db2level` in the db2inst1? ( do not add it as a comment here). How did you start the container (edit the question to show the full command-line mask any password, so we can see the volume options. You can always build your own image as noted in the answer.

Comment: Update, after restart of container, I see, that  DB2COMM='TCPIP,SSL' is changing to  DB2COMM='TCPIP'

Comment: What can be a reason ? Somewhere autostart script ?

Comment: I am just using default container https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2/
That's all